# Is there an `\edef` version of `\NewDocumentCommand` or `\newcommand` with optional arguments?

Tags: macros, loops, xparse

In a `\foreach` loop I want to define a bunch of macros with an *optional argument* (not shown in my example code). For this I use `\NewDocumentCommand`, but `\newcommand` would work, too.

But how do I get the advantages of `\edef` in those definitions? Without `\edef`ability I see no way of using the loop variable(s) to make variations in those definitions!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {one, two}{
    \globaldefs=1
    % I would want to use \eNewDocumentCommand here
    \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname\x\endcsname{}{
        \x
    }
}

\expandafter\show\csname one code\endcsname  % seems to show the "real" macro
\one  % fails, because \x was not expanded at definition time

\end{document}
```

<sub>Btw, how do you debug those new commands? `\show\macro` is useless... I noticed that the macro `\csname macro code\endcsname` gives the oportunity to see the macro once parsed/expanded (if)...</sub>

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand` isn't really supposed to be used programatically... You can always `\begingroup\edef\tmp{\endgroup\NewDocumentCommand\csname\x\endcsname}{}{\x}\tmp`, but I'm not sure of how good an idea that is. What _exactly_ are you trying to do? Perhaps there's a better way out...

Comment: `\globaldefs=1` in connection with `\NewDocumentCommand` or `\newcommand` has ***many*** side effects, not at all pleasant.

Comment: I was trying to generate a slew of commands which do similar things and have convenient names for use in my document. It seems to be better to go with `\gdef` or `\cs_new:Nn` without having an easy way to handle optional arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what this would be useful for.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\bunchdefine}{m}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \exp_args:Nc \NewDocumentCommand { ##1 } { } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\bunchdefine{one,two}

\begin{document}

\one

\two

\end{document}
```

As you see, there is no `\x` here, but just `#1` (doubled `#` because it's in the body of a definition) that represents the current item.

The mysterious `\exp_args:Nc` means: skip over the next token and form a control sequence name with the braced argument that follows, so it's essentially the same as

```
\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname##1\endcsname
```

but easier.

Comment: I still try to wrap my head around this: This needs no `\global` tricks, because there is no grouping (braces are around arguments, not in grouping function here). And...

Comment: ...you can’t get any command sequences resolved/expanded in a `\def`, but external parameters still are! (Not talking about the parameters of the to-be-defined function.) That is the big trick here, isn’t it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to expand the `\x` not only in the macro name, but also in the definition.  And you not only don't *need* an `\edef` form, but in this case, you probably don't actually *want* an `\edef` form.  That is to say, it is best to expand `\x` only once.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begin{document}

\foreach \x in {one, two, \today}{
    \globaldefs=1
     \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname\x\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter
    {\expandafter}\expandafter{\x*!@}
}

\one

\two

\csname\today\endcsname\\
= \csname September 5, 2019\endcsname
\end{document}
```

[image]

If one truly wanted the argument *fully* expanded, with the new TeX engines, one could introduce `\expanded`, as in

```
\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname\x\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter
{\expandafter}\expandafter{\expanded{\x*!@}}
```

Comment: `\globaldefs` has ***many*** side effects

Comment: @egreg In this case, it would appear to apply only inside the scope of the `\foreach` loop, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes, but its effects are on the subsidiary macros defined during processing of `\NewDocumentCommand` or `\newcommand` that should stay *local*.

Comment: @egreg I see what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

Is this sort of where you are headed?  That is, you have the arguments from `\newcommand` or even `\xparse` and the results from `\xdef`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\createname}[2]{% #1 = name, #2=contents
  \expandafter\xdef\csname #1\endcsname{#2}}

\begin{document}
\foreach \x in {one, two}{\createname{\x}{\x}}

\one

\two
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Applying `\romannumeral0`-expansion, using `\expandafter` and exchanging arguments you can probably achieve what you need without changing the value of the `\globaldefs`parameter and without using `\edef` at all:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\passfirsttosecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%%---------------------------------------------------------------
%%  \name <token sequence _without_ curly braces>{<tokens that yield the sequence "macroname">}  
%%  -> <token sequence _without_ curly braces>\macroname
%%
%%  Examples: \name{bar} -> \bar
%%            \name\newcommand*{bar}... -> \newcommand*\bar...
%%            \name\outer\global\long\def{bar}...  -> \outer\global\long\def\bar...
%%            \name\string{bar} -> \string\bar
%%            \name\name\let{foo}={bar} 
%%               -> \name\let\foo={bar}
%%               -> \let\foo=\bar
%%
%% The gist of the trick is: Due to #1#-notation \name processes one
%% argument which is delimited by a left-curly-brace.
%% Unlike other argument-delimiters the delimiting left-curly-brace will
%% not be removed but will be left in place when (La)TeX reads the
%% argument.
%% The tokens at the left of the delimiting left-curly-brace are to be
%% prepended after applying \csname...\endcsname to the tokens nested in
%% curly braces.
%%
\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\name{%
  \long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\nameinternal{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\nameinternal[2]{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}%
%%---------------------------------------------------------------
%% Scratch macro for accumulating calls to \NewDocumentCommand:
%% (Due to tikz's `\foreach` doing each iteration within a
%%  local scope accumulating needs to be done via global
%%  assignments, e.g.,in terms of \g@addto@macro.)
\newcommand\scratchy{}%
%%---------------------------------------------------------------

\def\scratchy{}%
\foreach \x in {one, two}{%
  \name\expandafter{g@addto@macro}\expandafter\scratchy\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral0% <-\romannumeral keeps searching digits, hereby expanding expandable things until
                  % finding something, e.g., a space, that terminates the digit-sequence.
                  % (\romannumeral will remove spaces that terminate digit sequences.)
    \expandafter\passfirsttosecond\expandafter{\x}{%
      \name\passfirsttosecond{\x}{ \NewDocumentCommand}{}%<- the space before  \NewDocumentCommand
    }%                                                   %   must be as it terminates \romannumeral0's
  }%                                                     %   searching for more digits. Thus \romannumeral 
}%                                                       %   only finds the non-positive number 0, swallows
                                                         %   that number not returning any token for it.
\scratchy    

\message{%
  Show the toplevel-definitions done by \string\NewDocumentCommand:^^J^^J%
}

\show\one
\show\two

\message{%
  You can also have a nice name-show also exhibiting the^^J%
  internal commands defined by \string\NewDocumentCommand:^^J^^J%
}

\name\show{one}
\name\show{one }
\name\show{one code}

\name\show{two}
\name\show{two }
\name\show{two code}

\begin{document}

\one

\two

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

---

Another variant where the assignments for the user-level-macros and the internal macros performed by `\NewDocumentCommand` will be "globalized" via `\globel\let⟨macro⟩=⟨macro⟩` could be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand\passfirsttosecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%%---------------------------------------------------------------
%%  \name <token sequence _without_ curly braces>{<tokens that yield the sequence "macroname">}  
%%  -> <token sequence _without_ curly braces>\macroname
%%
%%  Examples: \name{bar} -> \bar
%%            \name\newcommand*{bar}... -> \newcommand*\bar...
%%            \name\outer\global\long\def{bar}...  -> \outer\global\long\def\bar...
%%            \name\string{bar} -> \string\bar
%%            \name\name\let{foo}={bar} 
%%               -> \name\let\foo={bar}
%%               -> \let\foo=\bar
%%
%% The gist of the trick is: Due to #1#-notation \name processes one
%% argument which is delimited by a left-curly-brace.
%% Unlike other argument-delimiters the delimiting left-curly-brace will
%% not be removed but will be left in place when (La)TeX reads the
%% argument.
%% The tokens at the left of the delimiting left-curly-brace are to be
%% prepended after applying \csname...\endcsname to the tokens nested in
%% curly braces.
%%
\csname @ifdefinable\endcsname\name{%
  \long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\nameinternal{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\nameinternal[2]{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{ #1}%
}%

\foreach \x in {one, two}{%
  \expandafter\passfirsttosecond\expandafter{\x}{%
    \name\NewDocumentCommand{\x}{}%
  }%
  \name\name\global\let{\x}={\x}%
  \name\name\global\let{\x\space}={\x\space}%
  \name\name\global\let{\x\space code}={\x\space code}%
}%

\message{%
  Show the toplevel-definitions done by \string\NewDocumentCommand:^^J^^J%
}

\show\one
\show\two

\message{%
  You can also have a nice name-show also exhibiting the^^J%
  internal commands defined by \string\NewDocumentCommand:^^J^^J%
}

\name\show{one}
\name\show{one }
\name\show{one code}

\name\show{two}
\name\show{two }
\name\show{two code}

\begin{document}

\one

\two

\end{document}
```

The output will (apart from line-numbers with `\show`) be the same as with the first example.

The subtle difference is:

With the first example only the macro `\scratchy` will be changed globally.
`\one` and `\two` and the belonging internal macros will be defined within the current scope only.

With the second example `\one` and `\two` and the belonging internal macros will be (re)defined globally.

I write "(re)defined" because like `\newcommand` from the LaTeX 2e kernel `\NewDocumentCommand` will not throw an error-message in case a macro is undefined in the current scope but is defined in some superordinate scope. `\global\let...` will also not throw an error-message in case the control-sequence that is to be defined already is defined within the current scope or within some superordinate scope.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foobar}{}{This is foobar}
\show\foobar
\expandafter\show\csname foobar \endcsname
\expandafter\show\csname foobar code\endcsname

% This will throw an error-message:
\NewDocumentCommand{\foobar}{}{This is another foobar}
\show\foobar
\expandafter\show\csname foobar \endcsname
\expandafter\show\csname foobar code\endcsname

\begingroup
\let\foobar=\UnDEFInED
% This will not throw an error-message... :
\NewDocumentCommand{\foobar}{}{This is yet another foobar}
\global\let\foobar=\foobar
\expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname foobar \expandafter\endcsname\expandafter=\csname foobar \endcsname
\expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname foobar code\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter=\csname foobar code\endcsname
\endgroup

% ... but \foobar is redefined outside the local scope also/is redefined in
% all scopes:

\show\foobar
\expandafter\show\csname foobar \endcsname
\expandafter\show\csname foobar code\endcsname

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```